# Sql server data import - Error creating document : SolrInputDocument

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

I managed to set up a connection to my SQL server to import data into 
Solr. The idea is to import filetables but for now I first want to get it 
working using regular tables. So I created

***data-config.xml***

```xml
<dataConfig>   
  <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"     
     driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
     url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=inConnexion_Tenant2;integratedSecurity=true" />   
    <document>   
      <entity name="Dashboard" pk="id" query="SELECT Id,PublicId FROM foundation.Shops">   
        <field column="Id" name="Id"/>   
        <field column="PublicId" name="PublicId" /> 
      </entity>   
    </document>   
  </dataConfig>
```

***schema.xml***

I added

```xml
<field name="Id" 
       type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />    
<field name="PublicId" 
       type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
```

and changed uniqueKey entry to

```
<uniqueKey>Id</uniqueKey>
```

When I want to import my data (which is just data like Id: 5, PublicId: 
"test"), I get the following error in the logging.

> Error creating document : SolrInputDocument(fields: [PublicId=10065,​ 
>   Id=117])

Comment: Could it be that Solr expects your id field to be named `id`? Check the server log instead - it should have the complete error message.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but this did not help unfortunately. Maybe this is a stupid question but where can i find the server log ?

Comment: Ok i found it, and found indeed a more clearer error (This Indexschema is not mutable) and can now go on further fixing this :-)

Comment: Ok, i changed this in solrconfig.xml : <updateRequestProcessorChain name="add-unknown-fields-to-the-schema" default="${update.autoCreateFields:false}" (false instead of true) and now i'm indexing perfectly ! Thanks for the server log suggestion, i did not know there where logs elsewhere than the web admin !